# Android Java JSoup Search then retrieve results

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I am using JSoup to scrape/parse the data from [url] but I need to be able to also to fill in the Start Date and End Date fields on the webpage.

Any help would be appreciated on this problem,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to retrieve that data. If you look in your browsers developer tools network tab you can see there is a POST AJAX request done when you enter start+end dates and click search, and that request returns JSON. So you can use HTTP client to make such request and parse JSON with Jackson, GSON or any other JSON parser.

Or if you really want to enter data in form fields and submit a form - you'd have to use Selenium WebDriver for that. But that's a terrible overkill.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Could you please show/guide me how I can make the POST AJAX request? I know how to parse JSON so that I can do easily, it's just how to get the JSON I need help with.

Comment: Use Commons HTTPClient https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPCOMPONENTS/QuickStart